# How to use interface in this scenario

Tags: interface, c#-3.0

I am trying to setup interface method that will give version number:

```
var versionNumber = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

I am not sure how to implement this in an interface, so that the inheriting class can get the version number?

Comment: When defining an interface, you are just providing method signatures, not the implementations.  Just declare a method and leave out the implementation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public interface IVersionProvider
{
      string GetVersion();
}
```

implementation:

```
internal class /*or struct*/ VersionProvider : IVersionProvider
{
      public string GetVersion()
      {
           System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                   .GetName().Version.ToString();
      }
}
```

I made the class internal, because it doesn't need to be externally creatable:

```
public class Factory
{
      IVersionProvider GetVersionProvider() { return new VersionProvider(); }
}
```

Since the interface is public, external users will be able to call 'GetVersion' on it even though the implementation is private to the assembly.

Comment: What does last method do? class Factory? Do i need that?

Comment: @NoviceMe no you don't need it. It demonstrates how the implementation can be private, as the explanation above it says :)

Comment: Thanks! one more question - I also have a partial class for interface what should i put in there? As it is showing error?

Comment: it gives an error does not implement interface. And when i try to implement the interface it gives an error again.

Comment: @NoviceMe Sadly, I'm not psychic. Perhaps edit your question showing what you got?